# How to play against the Allgaier, Horny Defense?

Tags: opening, strategy, kings-gambit

The [Allgaier, Horny Defense](http://www.365chess.com/eco/C39_King%27s_Gambit_Accepted,_Allgaier,_Horny_defence) in the King's Gambit is given by the sequence:

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 g5 4. h4 g4 5. Ng5 h6 6. Nxf7 Kxf7 7. Qxg4 Nf6 8. Qxf4 Bd6
```

I'm a King's Gambit player, and I'm rated 1650 USCF, although I'm tactically much, much stronger (my biggest weakness is not knowing theory). This is a defense that my computer often plays against me (and assesses the position after the opening moves as +2 advantage for black, which doesn't seem reasonable to me), and I don't know how to deal with it. Any strategic/positional ideas that I should be aware of? I would also like to know how you guys would deal with the annoying

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 e5 2.f4 Qh4+ 3.g3 Qe7
```

as white. What kind of strategy should white adapt there?

Please don't berate my opening choice, and refrain from telling me to read up on theory. While that is a good idea, I am more interested in strategic ideas of this variation of the King's Gambit.

Comment: In the first position. I would like to be white (against a human in blitz :) ). I would, after the queen moved away, finish development, something like: d4, Nc3, Be3, 0-0-0, Bc4. And I think white forces are mobilized of the attack, and I think it is hard for black to finish development and/or get their king to safety. Black has to play very precise, which gives white good practical chances. I have not looked at this position with an engine, so I don't what to make my comment an answer.

Comment: By the way, are there any other ridiculous names of opening variations that you guys are familiar with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type your moves into Google it will actually find games that open that way.  It's quite cool. I use the move numbers as well as the actual moves.  Basically, a copy-paste of the first few moves.  Your game seems to be a ECO "C30".

For your Qh4+ question, I get [this link](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?result=1-0&gamekey=Qe2Qe7e4Qh4exd6Qxe2f4Qxe4fxe5d6g3e5/Nxe2Bxd6&notkey=Qe2Qe7e4Qh4exd6Qxe2f4Qxe4fxe5d6g3e5/xxx&title=1.%20e4%20e5%202.%20f4%20Qh4%20%203.%20g3%20Qe7%204.%20fxe5%20d6%205.%20exd6%20Qxe4%20%206.%20Qe2%20Qxe2%20%207.%20Nxe2%20Bxd6%20).

The gist is you get this continuation:

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 e5 2. f4 Qh4+ 3. g3 Qe7 4. fxe5 d6 5. exd6 Qxe4+ 6. Qe2
Qxe2+ 7. Nxe2 Bxd6
```

And you really don't have a lot to worry about.  In the games in the link above, White developed easily, Black's pawn structure was smashed, and White won pretty easy endgames.

Comment: I don't quite understand how black has a smashed pawn structure in the Qh4+ line that you showed me. It looks completely fine on move 8, and I may actually prefer to play on the black side with its open bishops. What strategic ideas am I missing for white here?

Comment: @chubbycantorset I was referring to the games posted in my link.